# Where to put ConnectionStrings in Onion Architecture

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, onion-architecture

I have an Interface `IApplicationConfig` that basically holds ConnectionStrings like for the Database, Blob Storage and other stuff. For every "executable" Project in my solution, like websites, command line tools etc. there is a concrete implementation of that interface which is configured to be resolved via dependency injection.

My question is, where should I put these `IApplicationConfig`-Implementations?

Next to my `web.config`/`app.config` in each "executable" Project? 
Or in Infrastructure, as `Project1Config.cs`, `Project2Config.cs` etc.?

Comment: Since its composition root settings, as close to the root as possible, this could possible be in `App_Start` or next to `web.config`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Preface

The way I have implemented managing configuration in one of my applications which is structured following the rules of Onion Architecture is as follows.

In this particular case I'm considering managing configuration (for instance logging as well) as an infrastructural concern, so that means that it's clearly not part of my application core. This is because it's an other layer.

### Philosophy course

To demonstrate the infrastructural concern please take a look a diagram below:

[image: Onion Architecture diagram]

<sub>* Image linked from the blog of [Shawn J Lee](https://shawnjlee.wordpress.com/tag/onion-architecture/).</sub>

Here you can see that logging takes place in the infrastructure slice or layer, I have stated that managing configuration is also an infrastructural concern.

Now, if anywhere in your architecture if you need to get a hold of your configuration manager implementation, you just ask for your `IApplicationConfig` in your constructors and get the proper implementation injected as per configured in your favorite [DI container/framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Dependency_injection_frameworks). This is called as the [Hollywood Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) or better yet Inversion Of Control.

Enough babbling you say? Now let's get straight to the technological demonstration...

### Implementation overview

You have asked about where to put actual implementations. I would structure these bits as:

- Application core layer(s)

  - Domain interfaces assembly
- Infrastructure layer

  - Configuration assembly
  - Dependency resolution assembly
- UI layer

  - Commandline assembly
  - Website assembly

Getting sleepy eh? Let's shift to higher gears now.

### Implementation example

I will try to illustrate here the actual implementation details in short.

#### Domain interfaces assembly

This is the layer where you put all the interface which the application core -and other layers as well- will work against or utilise.

Say we have `IApplicationConfig.cs`:

```
public interface IApplicationConfig
{
    ConnectionStringSettingsCollection GetConnectionStrings();
}
```

#### Configuration assembly

This is the place where you can have the actual implementation(s) of your `IApplicationConfig` interface. Having this as a separate assembly is questionable but it's really just an implementation detail, I personally store all my configuration managing implementations here.

For instance an implementation of `IApplicationConfig` could be as `ApplicationConfig.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationConfig : IApplicationConfig
{
    public ConnectionStringSettingsCollection GetConnectionStrings()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
    }
}
```

#### Dependency resolution assembly

This is where you "link" your interfaces with the needed implementations. Here I'm using Ninject and have created a [Ninject module](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) for it calling it as `ConfigModule`, a simple example:

```
public class ConfigModule : NinjectModule
{
    Bind<IApplicationConfig>().To<ApplicationConfig>();
}
```

#### And finally the Commandline/Website assembly

Usually these are the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) or the entry point of your applications where you compose your object graph. Having said this we now just need to load our Ninject module:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    var modules = new List<INinjectModule>
        {
            new ConfigModule(),
            new WhateverModule(),
            ...
        };

    kernel.Load(modules);
}
```

#### References you need to add Commandline/Website assembly

Having the interface contract and it's implementation separated, here you only need to add references to the:

- Dependency Resolution assembly
- Domain interfaces assembly

And now you can use your implementation in whichever layer you want.

### Afterword

This example has been taken from an actual application of mine, if you disagree with naming things, I agree... it's [not an easy thing](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) to do.

Comment: This is exactly how I do it. So you basically say it's an implementation detail where to put configuration

Comment: @Sandro Yes I think that it exactly is.

Comment: @Sandro did you ever succeed with this task?

Comment: Yes, I left the `IApplicationConfig` in the Core Project. And every Application (entry point) needs an implementation of it.

Comment: Yep, that sounds correct, great that you have done it.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the interface more specific so that it specifies what is needed for a specific class, or for that assembly, not for the application. If your data access is in its own assembly then the `ISettings` should be specific to that assembly, not shared with the host application. Then I'd also put the implementation in the assembly that requires it. The host application shouldn't "know" about the `ISettings` interface used by another assembly or be responsible for creating or providing an implementation.

If the implementation is going to read from app.config/web.config then I'd make sure it throws detailed exceptions if those settings are missing. That way someone depending on that assembly won't have to guess at what settings are needed.

The DI configuration for the data access assembly should reside either in that data access assembly or in another assembly altogether. The host application should not have to "know" so much about other assemblies that it contains detailed registrations for those assemblies. The host application just calls some external installer that registers the dependencies for that assembly.

It might also make sense to place your DI configuration in its own assembly. (Example [here](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/04/01/event-bus-implementation.html) using Windsor.) That way the data access assembly is built for dependency injection but doesn't depend on any one DI container. If necessary you could create a Windsor installer, an Autofac installer, etc. as needed (Depending on your environment or expected usage that could be overkill.)

Comment: I already have an own assembly for dependency resolution with the DI configurations organized in modules. Data access is in Infrastructure, but does that mean that retrieving its ConnectionString should be in the same assembly?

Comment: Ideally whatever assembly needs the configuration data, that's where the interface and the implementation should be. That way it's self contained.

Comment: Shouldn't the interfaces all go into Core?

Comment: The question is whether an interface is only used internally within an assembly or if it's the interface by means of which the assemblies will communicate with each other. If the data access assembly needs some settings to operate then there's no reason for any other assembly to deal with that (even if the settings appear in its .config file.) The only thing other assemblies would need to do is perhaps call something that configures DI. But they shouldn't need to know the details about what the DI is configuring.